# How to turn off view encapsulation for one property in Angular 2?

Tags: css, angular, typescript

I have the following styles:

```css
#right_content {
  padding: 30px 40px !important;
}
```

I store this inside a file `register.css`, which is bound to my `register.ts`.

The problem is that `<div id="right_content">` is located in a parent module, which means I can't directly modify its CSS properties from within `register.ts`.

```html
<div id="right_content">
  <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</div>
```

My `register.html` and `register.css` goes into the router outlet. I want to style the `#right_content` from `register.css`.

Is there any way I can turn off view encapsulation (or whatever the adding of the `_ngcontent-mxo-3` attributes is called), just for the above styles?

Comment: View encapsulation doesn't help you when you want to style a parent from a child or did I misunderstand your question. Can you please add more code that demonstrates how the styles and elements you want to style are releated?

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer `#right_content` is located in a parent component, so I can't change the styles from the CSS in the child component right now, simply because it adds an attribute to my CSS.

Comment: This doesn't help me. Please add more code that is the easiest way to make things clear. I'll add an answer but that's only a wild guess because I don't fully understand the question.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer Please check my update, see if that makes more sense.

Comment: So you actually want to style a parent from a child. That's just not supported. You can only style the component from itself or from an ancestor but you can't style an ancestor from a child or other descendant. The only way I can think of is adding styles to `<head>` imperatively.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer Yeah, okay then. You could update your answer to detail on `ViewEncapsulation.None`, and I'll accept it?

Comment: Use ::ng-deep, it works across all the browsers as suggested by [Günter Zöchbauer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37049049/2922178)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

**update**

`::slotted` is now supported by all new browsers and can be used with `ViewEncapsulation.ShadowDom

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::slotted

**original**

It is supported to create selectors that go through component boundaries even when `ViewEncapsulation` is `Emulated` (default)

```css
child-component ::ng-deep #right_content {
  padding: 30px 40px !important;
}
```

Allows to tile the `<xxx id="right_content">` from any ancestor

Comment: `>>>` and `/deep/` [are deprecated.](https://www.chromestatus.com/features/6750456638341120) 

Comment: use `::ng-deep`

Comment: [That's supposedly going away, too:](https://angular.io/guide/component-styles#deprecated-deep--and-ng-deep) _"The shadow-piercing descendant combinator is deprecated and [support is being removed from major browsers](https://www.chromestatus.com/features/6750456638341120) and tools. As such we plan to drop support in Angular (for all 3 of `/deep/`, `>>>` and `::ng-deep`). Until then `::ng-deep` should be preferred for a broader compatibility with the tools."_

Comment: It's going away when all browsers support style encapsulation natively and Angular drops `ViewEncapsulation.Emulated` which is currently the default and therefore unlikely to vanish soon ,-)

Comment: Same with `>>>` and `/deep/` but SASS only supports `::ng-deep` anymore this is why I suggest this nowadays.