# Style for mat-menu not working in angular using angular material and flex css

Tags: angular, drop-down-menu, angular-material, angular-flex-layout

I am trying to create a simple layout in angular 2 using angular material and flex css..

### Below is my code...

```
<div  class="background" >

<mat-toolbar fxLayout="row"   fxLayoutAlign="space-between  none" >

<div  fxLayout="column" > 
<p>SPACE STUDY</p>
<h6>Rockefeller FY 2018</h6>

<div  fxShow="true" fxHide.gt-sm="true" fxLayout="column" fxLayoutAlign="start none">

 <h6 [matMenuTriggerFor]="dashboarditems">
  <mat-icon style="transform: scale(1.2);">line_weight</mat-icon> </h6>

  <mat-menu  class="mat-menu-panel"  [overlapTrigger]="true" #dashboarditems="matMenu"><br/><br/>
<a  routerLink='/home' routerLinkActive='active'>
<span matTooltip="HOME"><mat-icon style="color:lightgreen;">home</mat-icon></span></a><br/><br/><br/>

<a >
<span matTooltip="SPACE SURVEY"><mat-icon style="color:deeppink;">explore</mat-icon></span></a><br/><br/><br/>

<a  >
<span matTooltip="SPACE ADMIN"><mat-icon style="color:lightblue;">account_circle</mat-icon></span></a><br/><br/><br/>

<a >
<span matTooltip="REPORTS"><mat-icon style="color: orange;">assignment</mat-icon></span></a><br/><br/><br/>

<a >
<span matTooltip="JOINT USE"><mat-icon style="color:yellow;">supervisor_account</mat-icon></span></a><br/><br/><br/>

<a  >
<span matTooltip="HELP"><mat-icon style="color:red;">help</mat-icon></span></a><br/><br/><br/>
  </mat-menu>
</div>


</div>

<div fxLayout="row"  fxShow="true" fxHide.lt-md="true" >
<button mat-raised-button routerLink='/home' routerLinkActive='active'>
<span matTooltip="HOME"><mat-icon style="color:lightgreen;">home</mat-icon></span></button>

<button mat-raised-button >
<span matTooltip="SPACE SURVEY"><mat-icon style="color:deeppink;">explore</mat-icon></span></button>

<button mat-raised-button >
<span matTooltip="SPACE ADMIN"><mat-icon style="color:lightblue;">account_circle</mat-icon></span></button>

<button mat-raised-button >
<span matTooltip="REPORTS"><mat-icon style="color: orange;">assignment</mat-icon></span></button>

<button mat-raised-button  >
<span matTooltip="JOINT USE"><mat-icon style="color:yellow;">supervisor_account</mat-icon></span></button>

<button mat-raised-button >
<span matTooltip="HELP"><mat-icon style="color:red;">help</mat-icon></span></button>
</div>

</mat-toolbar>

</div>


<style>

.background {
/* Remember to use the other versions for IE 10 and older browsers! */
display: flex;
min-height: 100%;
font-family: 'verdana', sans-serif;
color: #fff;
height:100vh;
background: #222222;
background: #16222A; /* fallback for old browsers */
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(to top, #16222A , #3A6073); /* Chrome 10-25, Safari 5.1-6 */
background: linear-gradient(to top, #16222A , #3A6073); /* W3C, IE 10+/ Edge, Firefox 16+, Chrome 26+, Opera 12+, Safari 7+ */
}

p{
font-size:20px;
font-weight:bold;
font-family: 'verdana', sans-serif;
margin:3px;
}

h6{
    font-size:12px;
    font-weight:bold;
    font-family: 'verdana', sans-serif;
}

.mat-raised-button{
    text-align:left;
    border-radius:10px;
    font-size:11px;
    font-weight:bold;
    font-family: 'verdana', sans-serif;
    color:white;
    background:transparent;
}

.mat-icon {
    transform: scale(1.5);
}

.matTooltip{
    font-size:11px;
    font-weight:bold;
    font-family: 'verdana', sans-serif;
    }

.mat-menu-panel {
    min-width: 35px;
    max-width: 280px;
    overflow: auto;
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
    max-height: calc(100vh - 48px);
    border-radius: 2px;
    outline: 0;
    background: transparent;
    padding-left: 10px;
}
</style>
```

### This is my output

[image]

Here I am trying to change the background color for the mat-menu container to transparent and also set some other styles.

When i change in console its getting reflected back as shown below

[image]

But when i applied the same changes in my code , the styles are not being applied.

I also tries explicitly adding class="mat-menu-panel" in the component and the div in which i added the mat-menu.

But still the styles are not being applied..

can anybody please help me to fix this styling..

Comment: try to add !important at the end of your css property

Comment: just !important..?

Comment: just give a try bro or give a example code.So that it will be easy to investigate

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mat-formfield-flex-layout-vc3fsj?file=app%2Fapp.component.html... can you please access this stackblitz demo

Comment: Your stackblitz is broken. Please fix it.

Comment: @G.Tranter ... can you please check this out..........https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mat-formfield-flex-layout-vc3fsj?file=app%2Fapp.component.html

Comment: It is still broken.

Comment: i fixed it ... https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mat-formfield-flex-layout-vc3fsj?file=index.html

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The style is not applied because of Angular [view encapsulation](https://angular.io/guide/component-styles#view-encapsulation).

You can see here that your `.mat-menu-panel` got **encapsulated**:

[image: mat-menu-panel after view encapsulation]

#### Solutions - Three options:

- **turn off the view encapsulation:**

  setting the `encapsulation` component property to `ViewEncapsulation.None` like so:

```js
    @Component({
        selector: 'app-root',
        templateUrl: './app.component.html',
        encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None, // disable ViewEncapsulation
    })
```

- or put the mat-menu-panel style on the global style: `/styles.scss`
- (will be deprecated "soon") use `::ng-deep` as mentioned in this thread: [how-to-turn-off-view-encapsulation-for-one-property-in-angular-2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37043433/how-to-turn-off-view-encapsulation-for-one-property-in-angular-2)

#### Pay attention:

Some of your properties are getting overridden by the default style so you will have to add `!important` to each of them or **use more specific selector**.

For example I added `myMenu` class into your `mat-menu`:

[image: .myMenu class]

and then, update the css selector to:

```css
.mat-menu-panel.myMenu {
    min-width: 35px;
    max-width: 280px;
    overflow: auto;
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
    max-height: calc(100vh - 48px);
    border-radius: 2px;
    outline: 0;
    background: transparent;
    padding-left: 10px !important;
}
```

Comment: Set `encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None` and set the CSS at the root of the component `mat-menu` is used. To avoid affecting other `mat-menu` provide different CSS Class name to each of the menus. Thank you so much @jury